# How to play a video on a php page?

Tags: php, html, video

I'm trying to play a video on my site, but when it is played on a different networks its super slow.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
    <video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" autoplay="true" width="100%" height="740" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">


 <!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE -->
 <!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><source src="unfriended.mp4" type='video/mp4'><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE -->
 <!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><source src="unfriended.webm" type='video/webm'><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE -->
 <!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE --><!-- VIDEO NAME HERE -->


</video>
```

Do I need to set some magical php stuff up to compress the file or something?

Comment: This is just HTML5, what does it have to do with PHP?  If it's slow, that could depend on a lot of things.  The client's bandwidth, the server's bandwidth, the client's processor speed, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling it was that, thanks

Comment: You could try to deliver the video files via a PHP script that gzips it (and sets the correct headers), but I'm not sure if browsers support gziping in the `<video>` tag.

Comment: Hmm okay I'll have a look around

Comment: also, make sure you optimize your video for streaming - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977044/html5-lagging-videos-mp4/26002847#26002847 - and that the server correctly handles byte range requests