# Best way to "universally embed" and avi video inside and html page

Tags: html, video, embed, avi

I have a video.avi file and and html page on a server, and I would like to "embed universally" my video inside the html so that people could see it. By *universally* I mean in a way where I would be the less dependent on browsers/video viewers the viewers could have. In fact (I am dreaming for sure) I would like everyone with every "decent" "recent" browser to be able to see it...

I know how noob it sound, but I had a working html code who stopped doing the job a couple of weeks ago (the video does not appear anymore) and I would like to solve the issue once for all...

(I don't want to upload my video to youtube and to embed a youtube video though.)

Comment: you won't be able to use an avi, you'll need to convert to a container/codec supported by HTML5 `<video>` tag (mp4, wemb, ogg, possibly all three for best coverage). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977044/html5-lagging-videos-mp4/26002847#26002847 for a hint on converting your avi to mp4 with the (free) ffmpeg utility

Answer (score 0):

I indeed opted for :

```
<video width="1020" height="310" controls>
<source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and realized a pretty decent conversion with one of the first freewares I found online, I don't want to advertise for.